# If someone knows your wifi password AND is out of wifi range, does it present any particular risks?

Tags: passwords, wifi

This is a close matchup for [If someone knows your wifi password can they hack your router?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/260859/if-someone-knows-your-wifi-password-can-they-hack-your-router)

I gave someone my general (not the guest-specific) wifi password, but they flew home to another continent.  My partner is concerned about whether that's a risk.  I have no reason to suspect the person of anything, but I can't vouch for them either - my kid knows them, I don't.

Assume a modern home router with the default admin password changed.  The router has not been specially configured to allow remote configuration.  Assume also that the person knowing the password may have saved the router's ISP-issued IP.

Does the fact that the "attacker" is out of wifi range alter the answers given to that question? (be mindful of badly configured network, unchanged admin passwords, etc...)  However it seems to me basic security practices would be to just ignore wifi credentials entirely when the router is accessed from the internet.

In theory I guess the attacker could give your credentials to someone local who could then do their bad stuff on wifi.  In my case however, I live in a high rise, with strict elevator access controls.

p.s. Yes, yes, I may just end up changing the password.  But what are risks if I don't?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that your WiFi password has no relation to any other relevant password, then somebody who knows the password and is not in reach of your WiFi cannot use it directly to harm you.

But, one could use such leaked credentials to build traps. Mobile devices often try to automatically connect to a network which has the same name and password as a network they were connected before. So given the knowledge of both the password and (likely) the WiFi name (SSID) one could set up a rogue WiFi router somewhere where you live to catch anybody using your network (i.e. family members) and then sniff their traffic or even infect the devices.

There is no need that the person does this itself - these credentials could be given to others or added to public lists as [schroeder suggests in his answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/273487/37315).

Answer (score 0):

I'd be concerned about that person adding my password to one of the many "wifi password" sites. These maintain databases of wifi APs, their location, and the password.

But only you know the character of this person.